# Share PDF in Chromium to WhatsApp/Mail/

Tags: pdf, sharing

I am looking at a PDF file in the Chromimum browser.

Now I would like to share the file.

I am missing this symbol:

[image: share-symbol]

On mobile phones sharing is easy. How to share the file with Ubuntu?

[image: pdf-in-chromium]

Comment: Open Whatsapp/Mail and upload the file there? You already know the location from the address bar. Desktops do not have such a share button. Alternatively, you can open an issue at Chromium bug tracker to add such a share button.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi as a user I would like things to be simple. "Reduce cognitive load" (aka "don't make me think") is the mantra successful GUIs.